# Sound is Jerky, choppy and distorted in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, soundcard, sound-blaster, oss-sound-system

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I am getting jerky sound. The sound works perfectly in Windows 7 so it is not a hardware issue.

I am using a Creative Sound Blaster Audigy 2 Value sound card with a 5.1 speaker setup.

This also does not seem to be a problem with Ubuntu as the same thing happened when I tried OpenSuse 12.2 which I have replaced with Ubuntu 12.10 hoping that this will sort out the problem.

Sound works fine on boot up when I get to the log on screen as I hear the drum, but when I test the speakers after I have logged in, sometimes there is sound and sometimes there is no sound and when testing the speakers I get a jerky, choppy and distorted sound back I have made changes to the following files `daemon.conf` and `default.pa`.

Comment: I hope this will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/182164/lots-of-static-crackling-noises-after-alsa-hda-dkms-installation/270947#270947

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, with the same AudioSoundCard.

I see this problem when trying to hear some music with Rythmbox. The sound is choppy and is changing from one side to other (several times per second) everytime.

I was browsing the sound options, and founded that changing the output scheme for another (it seems to work fine with Stero Output everytime), the problem fixes, but just for the current song. Next one repeats the problem until I change for another output scheme.

If I try to test speakers, the problems it's the same testing each speaker. And it does not sound just the speaker I choose, but the sound keeps moving from one speaker to other.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to this question. It would have been better if this was a comment. Thanks for understanding.