# How to convert .aif audio files to mp3?

Tags: sound, convert, sox, aif

I have audio files with `.aif` extensions (AIFF/Amiga/Mac audio). How to play them and, more important: **how to convert them** to mp3 or other more common audio format?

---

update: trying to run a command found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1000116), namely `for i in *.aif; do sox "$i" "$i.wav"; done`, and having `sox` already installed, i get an error like

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file 'filename': Unsupported AIFC
>   compression type `ima4'

---

`exiftool` provides info such as:

```
File Size                       : 41 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:04:23 15:54:02+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : AIFC
MIME Type                       : audio/x-aiff
Format Version Time             : 1990:05:23 14:40:00
Num Channels                    : 1
Num Sample Frames               : 1257382
Sample Size                     : 0
Sample Rate                     : 16000
Compression Type                : Unknown (ima4)
```

---

for some reason `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52` would not work (Unable to locate package - but Multiverse is enabled)

Comment: Have you seen e.g." How to play AIFF (AIF) files in Ubuntu" http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1000116 and "Convert Aiff to MP3 with ffmpeg on ubuntu" http://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/convert-aiff-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu/

Comment: sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52

Comment: ffmpeg -i inputfile.aif -f mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192000 -ar 44100 outputfile.mp3

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/convert-aif-mp3-525455/ check this link

Comment: @XxxXxx - are you sure `libavcodec-unstripped-52` is still around?  i am in Quantal, multiverse repo is enabled and there is no `libavcodec-unstripped-52` to be found. but there is a `libavcodec-extra-53`

Comment: i dont know ....that is why i have pasted as an comment not an answer... i thought may be this will help you...

Comment: @XxxXxx - indeed it did. [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/286567/47206) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/286684/47206)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finding this solution [here](http://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/convert-aiff-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu/) (also recommended in comments), for some reason `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52` would not work (Unable to locate package - but Multiverse is enabled).

But in Synaptic I have seen that I had `libavcodec53` installed, but not `libavcodec-extra-53`. Installing the later has uninstalled the former, and then the command `ffmpeg -i inputfile.aif -f mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192000 -ar 44100 outputfile.mp3` worked.

So,

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libavutil-extra-51 libdirac-encoder0 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0
  libopenjpeg2 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libx264-123
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libavcodec53 libavutil51
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavcodec-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51 libdirac-encoder0 libopencore-amrnb0
  libopencore-amrwb0 libopenjpeg2 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libx264-123
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,656 kB of archives.
```

After this, other commands and actions are now working, including those to convert to mp3, like `avconv -i %f %f.mp3`. To see that in Terminal, I have added to Thunar custom actions: `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "avconv -i %f %f.mp3"`. (In Gnome Terminal, create a new profile called "new1" and edit it ('Edit/Profiles/Title and Command') to 'When command exits: Hold the Terminal open'.)

Even after this, the **aif files cannot be played by Totem, Parole, Xine, DeaDBeeF, Banshee or VLC**; even in **Audacity** the sound is badly distorted, just like in **Audacious**. But **mplayer (SMPlayer, Gnome Player, Mplayer) can play them just fine**.

Comment: if you feel Crackly sound http://askubuntu.com/questions/182164/lots-of-static-crackling-noises-after-alsa-hda-dkms-installation/270947#270947

Comment: @XxxXxx - that bad sound happens only for the `.aif` files

Answer (score 16):

Following Toon's Unix Recipes, for example (and the above examples):

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i track1.aiff -f mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192000 -ar 44100 track1.mp3
```

(Older versions of Ubuntu can use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`.)

Comment: "doesn't exist anymore in Ubuntu 14.04" ...what? Check this https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Comment: update - newer ubuntu have ffmpeg back in action. like 16.04

Answer (score 3):

There is one more program named assoundconverter and you can install it with your terminal
`sudo apt-get install soundconverter` .

from the `EDIT` -> `Preferences` options you can customize it as you want.
[image]

This will convert any format to mp3 and other. hope that helps.

Comment: didn't work on `.aif` files as far as i can tell, but i'll recheck

Answer (score 1):

To convert to [FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC):

```
flac [INPUTFILE]
```

(If you find `flac` isn’t installed: `sudo apt-get install flac`.)

[flac man page here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flac), showing options.

---

Similarly, in order to convert to mp3:

```
sudo apt-get install lame

lame [inputfile]
```

Comment: Converting to flac with that command is working for me with aif files downloaded from http://www.bigsoundbank.com/