# Unclear Sound on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, asus, alsa, realtek, noise

I own an Asus K55vm running ubuntu 13.04 with updated alsa and pulseaudio.
The sound on my laptop is clearly unclear at 100% volume on all applications.
The sound was clear on windows.
I think it uses alc270 sound card.
Any help would be great

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/182164/lots-of-static-crackling-noises-after-alsa-hda-dkms-installation/270947#270947

Comment: @Qasim Hey that doesnt solve anything, thanks a lot though