# PulseAudio is not working at all

Tags: sound, 13.04, pulseaudio

I installed PulseAudio two weeks ago and since then I've been trying to open it and it doesn't.

Does anyone have any solution?

P.S. I have a horrible Speaker set.

Answer (score 1):

PulseAudio is included and configured for you already in Ubuntu by default, you don't have to run it manually. So, if you have some problems with sound, I don't think that is because of PulseAudio. It could be a bug or maybe a hardware problem.

You can check it if is working ok with `pulseaudio --check` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) - *produces no output on the console except for errors to stderr.*

See `man pulseaudio` for more informations.

Also, for more help, you can follow this question: [Sound problems after upgading to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291165/sound-problems-after-upgading-to-13-04) and this [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

Answer (score -1):

You could try to remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio
```

and update and reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

If this does'nt work, maybe you can find some help in one of these steps:

[Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Comment: You may want to read this: http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/