# Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 disabled track pad, brightness, sound on Lenovo Z570

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, updates, lenovo, 13.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 using Ubuntu's software update. It seemed to go all right, however after the system restarted and booted up Ubuntu 13.10, it began experiencing several problems. Some of them were due to expected conflicts with the updated OS, however right now I cannot figure out why certain hardware functions are now "broken" and how to fix them.

As far as I can tell, these are the sound (permanently muted), mic (picks up no sound), brightness (set at maximum brightness regardless of using keyboard shortcuts or moving the screen brightness slider) and trackpad (mouse does not move, however plugged-in USB mouse does)

This sounds to me like a driver issue, however I cannot figure out how to re-enable my drivers, re-install them, or whatever I have to do here. This did not happen durring my upgrades from 12.04 to 12.10, or 12.10 to 13.04, so I'm at a total loss as to why this happened this time around.

My computer is a Lenovo Z570, dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 from GRUB 2. Windows is working fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: You may have to re-configure your packages and/or drivers installed in your system. Hope after it would work properly.. Execute these commands : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')` , `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`. If you get any error at any particular command just mention it with the error message. Once all commands execute well restart your system once. See what happens..

Answer (score 0):

For sound, try this:
[Sound problems after upgading to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291165/sound-problems-after-upgading-to-13-04)

For the trackpad, I had for some weird reason a missing package, and doing

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

resolved the issue. Maybe it works for you too?

For the brightness I'm at a loss. I have a somewhat similar problem with the brightness, so hang on :)

Answer (score 0):

For screen brightness the following may help you (for me this worked on G510 core i5 4th gen free dos).

Use terminal and give the code:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add `acpi_backlight=vendor` after quiet splash. So the line reads as:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and without fail update the grub using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart.